# Does adding a new function call at the END of an orchestration require versioning?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have a need to add a call to an activity function at the end of an existing orchestration (that has in-flight instances).

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-versioning?tabs=csharp#changing-orchestrator-logic) call out that going from:

```
[FunctionName("FooBar")]
public static Task Run([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
{
    bool result = await context.CallActivityAsync<bool>("Foo");
    await context.CallActivityAsync("Bar", result);
}
```

to this:

```
[FunctionName("FooBar")]
public static Task Run([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
{
    bool result = await context.CallActivityAsync<bool>("Foo");
    if (result)
    {
        await context.CallActivityAsync("SendNotification");
    }

    await context.CallActivityAsync("Bar", result);
}
```

is not allowed because it is a change to orchestrator logic and could break replay behavior.

But what if instead the `await context.CallActivityAsync("SendNotification");` was added at the END of the orchestration. Effectively:

```
[FunctionName("FooBar")]
public static Task Run([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
{
    bool result = await context.CallActivityAsync<bool>("Foo");
    await context.CallActivityAsync("Bar", result);

    // New activity function called here, right before exiting orchestration.
    await context.CallActivityAsync("SendNotification");
}
```

Would adding to the end of an orchestration cause a non-deterministic orchestration error for in-flight instances?

Comment: I *think* that would be ok. Not 100% sure though.. I'd just make a new version side-by-side.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I most definitely can do that. It's a complex orchestration that has changed over the years (I'm on v10 already hah) and was just trying to gauge whether it was truly necessary in this case to support another version.